# jQuery / JavaScript: Subtract current 'value' till 'Zero'

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html, web

here is a simple one; suppose I have a script that pulls a value from a database and each time a user clicks a button the value is reduced by a single count, how do I prevent the value from decreasing to below zero,

```
 if(count>0){
           $.post(sessionStorage.server, { count:count ,request:"counter",user:sessionStorage.sname });
        }

if(count==0){
            alert("Your value is now zero");
            sessionStorage.clear();
            sessionStorage.msg="Logged off, ran out of clicks";
            window.location.href = "../index.html";
        }
```

Comment: Your code seems fine to me, what is not working? How is counter getting incremented.

Comment: as already answered, I guess you only missed the `else`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
if(count==0){
            alert("Your value is now zero");
            sessionStorage.clear();
            sessionStorage.msg="Logged off, ran out of clicks";
            window.location.href = "../index.html";
        }
else if(count>0){
           $.post(sessionStorage.server, { count:count ,request:"counter",user:sessionStorage.sname });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this one

```
if(count==0){
```

with this one

```
if(count<=0){
```

Answer (score 0):

The orig code looks well, just a little suggestions

1.add else will improve js performace

```
if(count>0){
       $.post(sessionStorage.server, { count:count ,request:"counter",user:sessionStorage.sname });
}
else if(count==0){
        alert("Your value is now zero");
        sessionStorage.clear();
        sessionStorage.msg="Logged off, ran out of clicks";
        window.location.href = "../index.html";
}
```

2.Check the count at server side, never trust js validation